# How to generate a list of columns which have missing values in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, database, pandas, list, dataframe

This is what I have tried (and it works):

```
req_col = []
for i in df.columns:
  if  df[i].isnull().sum()>0:
    req_col.append(i)
print(req_col)
```

I tried to modify the above code to make it concise (and this works too):

```
req_col1 = [i for i in df.columns if df[i].isnull().sum()>0]
```

Both the above give me the following result (which is a list of columns having missing values):

```
['LotFrontage', 'Alley',...............,'MiscFeature']
```

**What are the other concise/generally used/better methods to do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
df.columns[df.isna().any()]
```

To get it as a list:

```
list(df.columns[df.isna().any()])
```

or

```
df.columns[df.isna().any()].tolist()
```

Comment: I could use list(df.columns[df.isna().any()]) to get it in list

Answer (score 1):

```
df.columns[df.isna().any()].tolist()
```